# Need two rows data into one row using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, union

i have two columns in an asg table which will have two assignment numbers according to the assignment type.
i.e. if `assignment type= WT` , then the assignment number will be WT1 ,when its "W", number will be W1

The table is as follows :

```
  ASG_NUMBER     ASG_TYPE person_id   JOB_CODE       ORG_CODE...........
    W1              W        12       TECHNINICAN    LOC_org
    WT1             WT       12        -             -
```

Now, i have to create a query which fetches the workterm number and the assignment number in one row. I made a query hwich is fetching two different rows.
I want the below column :

```
W_aSG_NUMBER     WT_ASG_NUMBER    JOB_CODE   ORG_CODE ....
```

THE JOB_CODE and org_code and everything should be according to the W row only.

I used union in my query but it is giving two rows for this one :

```
select w_ASG_NUMBER,
wt_asg_number
ASG_TYPE,
JOB_CODE,
ORG_CODE
from 
(select  w_ASG_NUMBER,
'' wt_asg_number,
ASG_TYPE,
JOB_CODE,
ORG_CODE
from asg_table 
where asg_type ='W'

UNION 
select '' w_ASG_NUMBER,
 wt_asg_number,
ASG_TYPE,
JOB_CODE,
ORG_CODE
from asg_table 
where asg_type ='WT')
```

Comment: Does this table only have 2 rows in it? If not, how do you know which W rows go with which WT rows? (ie, is there a key)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm

Comment: asg_id is common @kfinity

Comment: @Tejash yes as it is assumption based i added an id otherwise its person_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following query:

```
SELECT A1.ASG_NUMBER AS ASG_NUMBER,
A2.ASG_NUMBER AS WT_NUMBER,
A1.JOB_CODE,
A1.ORG_CODE
FROM ASG_TABLE A1 JOIN ASG_TABLE A2
ON A1.PERSON_ID = A2.PERSON_ID
AND A1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE = A2.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
AND A1.ASG_TYPE || 'T' = A2.ASG_TYPE 
AND A1.EFFECTIVE_SEQUENCE = A2.EFFECTIVE_SEQUENCE
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN A1.ASG_TYPE = 'W' THEN A1.ASG_NUMBER END) AS ASG_NUMBER,
MAX(CASE WHEN A1.ASG_TYPE = 'WT' THEN A1.ASG_NUMBER END) AS WT_NUMBER,
MAX(A1.JOB_CODE),
MAX(A1.ORG_CODE)
FROM ASG_TABLE A1
WHERE A1.PERSON_ID = <YOUR_PERSON_ID>
AND A1.ASG_TYPE IN ('W','WT')
GROUP BY
A1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 
A1.EFFECTIVE_SEQUENCE
```

I know these columns because I have worked on it. :)

Cheers!!

Comment: this would only work if I have these columns only to fetch.. I have to fetch the org_code, job_code and so on and so forth..

Comment: this will return two rows otherwise

Comment: You should go with first query then.

Answer (score 0):

here it is using keep dense rank
here is the fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f67d6/32

```
    select asg_id,
 MAX( asg_number) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY  decode(ASG_TYPE,'W',1, 0)) W_asg_number,
 MAX( asg_number) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY  decode(ASG_TYPE,'WT',1, 0)) WT_asg_number,
 MAX( JOB_CODE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY  decode(ASG_TYPE,'W',1, 0)) JOB_CODE,
 MAX( ORG_CODE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY  decode(ASG_TYPE,'W',1, 0)) ORG_CODE
 from mytable
 group by asg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show W rows along with their WT asg_number. You say, we can find the WT row that belongs to a W row by comparing their asg_id.

One approach is to select the WT.asg_number in a subquery:

```
with w as (select * from mytable where asg_type = 'W')
  , wt as (select * from mytable where asg_type = 'WT')
select w.*, (select asg_number from wt where wt.asg_id = w.asg_id) as wt_asg_number
from w;
```